# What does $b^*$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What is this notation, my book explains nothing of it. I've colored it in yellow!

I am guessing it stands for $b^{-1}$ or $b^1$?

[image]

Comment: They just mean that $b$ and $b^*$ are two different vectors. No relationship between them.

Comment: That *really* depends on the context. But it seems like Christopher is right, and the star is just used to differentiate between $b$ and $b^*$ (that is really confusing, as most of the time $*$ is some operation, so it's kind of like writing $-b$ for something different from $b$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually $b^*$ is the complex conjugate of $b$. That is, if $b_{j}=x+iy$, then $b_{j}^{*}=x-iy$ (with $b\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}$ and $b^*\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times n}$). In this context it seems like the author is just trying to use two different symbols. Ideally, you should not use this notation for anything other than complex conjugates in linalg.

Comment: This book "Introduction to Linear Algebra: Foruth Edition" by Gilbert Strang has to be one of the worst books I have ever encountered. Zero pedagogy.

Comment: @par: Well, it is also commonly used to denote some other kind of conjugate (like conjugate transpose of a matrix). Karl: I'm inclined to agree, based on this alone. In that case, maybe you should find another one? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately my homework is based on it and goes towards my grading (the torture!). Pedagogy does not exist in Korea(I am currently an exchange student in Korea).

Comment: @KarlMorrison Email your prof?

Comment: Done done and done! He simply refers to his assistant, which he isn't very good in English plus I always get referred to the class lectures and book! Having a conversation with him takes quite a while due to the language barrier haha.